# Change anchor location throughout TikZ foreach loop?

Tags: labels, loops, anchor

I have some TikZ code to generate a unit circle with `N` evenly spaced vectors going from the center to the circumference of the circle.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}     
\newcommand\wpic{4}
\newcommand\wcir{3}
\newcommand\Nm1{7}
\draw[help lines, color=gray, dashed] (-\wpic,-\wpic) grid (\wpic,\wpic);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-\wpic,0)--(\wpic,0) node[right]{Re};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-\wpic)--(0,\wpic) node[above]{Im};
\draw[blue,thick] (0,0) circle(\wcir cm);
\foreach \i in {0,...,7} {
    \draw[line width=2pt,red,-stealth] (0,0)--({\wcir*cos(deg(2*pi*(\i/8)))},{\wcir*sin(deg(2*pi*(\i/8)))}) node[anchor= south west]{$e^{i2\pi\frac{\i}{8}}$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note that the command `\Nm1` represents the number of vectors minus 1, since we loop from `0` to `N-1`. This produces the following picture:

[image]

I want to label the vectors so that they all look nice, like the first three vectors corresponding to 0/8, 1/8, and 2/8. For example, is there a way to specify the anchor location based on the angle of the vector? How would you accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use `label={<angle>:<label>}` for your node and leave the node contents empty. Then you can use the angle you already calculated to determine the position of the label.

A few suggestions:

1. Use polar coordinates: `(\t:\wcir)` is much simpler (and more efficient) than calculating rectangular coordinates with `sin` and `cos`.
2. Use `evaluate` to avoid calculating the angle more than once. I set the angle to `\t`.

Here is the code:

```
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \t using deg(2*pi*(\i/8))] in {0,...,7} {
    \draw[line width=2pt,red,-stealth] (0,0)--(\t:\wcir) node[label={\t:$e^{i2\pi\frac{\i}{8}}$}]{};
}
```

[image]

The result is probably not what you want, because the axes make the label placement somewhat awkward. If you want a custom placement for each label, you can change your `\foreach` loop to include a label angle: `\foreach\i/\l in ...` allows you to choose the angle for each label:

```
\foreach \i/\l [evaluate=\i as \t using deg(2*pi*(\i/8))] in {0/45,1/45,2/45,3/135,4/135,5/225,6/-45,7/-45} {
    \draw[line width=2pt,red,-stealth] (0,0)--(\t:\wcir) node[label={\l:$e^{i2\pi\frac{\i}{8}}$}]{};
}
```

[image]

If the labels are too far for your taste, you can adjust them by setting `label distance=` to a negative value

```
node[label={[label distance=-6pt]\l:$e^{i2\pi\frac{\i}{8}}$}]{}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First note that because `1` is not a letter (its standard category code is 12, not 11), your `\newcommand\Nm1{7}` doesn't do what you presumably expected: it

- defines command `\Nm` taking no argument and having `1` as its replacement text,
- then typesets `7` in the current font. At the moment your code does this, the current font is `\nullfont`, therefore TeX prints the following warning:

  > Missing character: There is no 7 in font nullfont!

Now, regarding the picture, some fine tuning of angles and offsets seems necessary in order to obtain a really nice output. Here is a possibility using:

- two `pgfmath` arrays (`\myangles` and `\myoffsets`);
- a few automatic computations for the typeset formula (special case for `\i` = 0 and simple computation of the numerator in the argument of the exponential function);
- no empty node (@SandyG used the `label` key applied to an empty node; here, we achieve a similar effect using `anchor={\myangles[\i] + 180}` for the node containing the formula—not saying that the empty node is bad).

Little advantage of the `pgfmath` arrays, as compared to stuff like `\foreach \i/\l in {0/45,1/45,2/45,3/135,4/135,5/225,6/-45,7/-45}`: we don't have to enumerate the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7—these can be automatically generated.

Note: the `[evaluate=\i as \t using deg(2*pi*(\i/8))]` was taken from [Sandy G's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646668/73317).

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\wpic}{4}
  \newcommand{\wcir}{3}

  \draw[help lines, color=gray, dashed] (-\wpic,-\wpic) grid (\wpic,\wpic);
  \draw[->, very thick] (-\wpic,0) -- (\wpic,0) node[right]{Re};
  \draw[->, very thick] (0,-\wpic) -- (0,\wpic) node[above]{Im};
  \draw[blue, thick] (0,0) circle[radius=\wcir cm];

  \def\myangles{{     52,    42,    42,   135,   135,   225,   -38,    -45}}
  \def\myoffsets{{0.22em, 0.2em, 0.3em, 0.1em, 0.3em, 0.3em, 0.3em, 0.18em}}

  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \t using deg(2*pi*(\i/8))] in {0,...,7} {
    \draw[very thick, red!90!black, ->] (0,0) -- (\t:\wcir) coordinate (P);
    \path (P) ++(\myangles[\i]:\myoffsets[\i])
      node[anchor={\myangles[\i] + 180}]
        {$\ifnum\i=0 1\else e^{i\frac{\the\numexpr 2*\i\relax \pi}{8}}\fi$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S.: in the future, please provide *complete* compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.